# DataAction confusion in PlatonScript

Tags: jplaton

I have been asked to do apply some changes in a jPlaton package unit. The main set of this unit has some DataActions associated with it which appear on the top right corner of the screen. How to these DataActions trigger procedures in the code.xml??? Do I have to write any JavaScript inside PlatonScript?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the actions binded with a set (which means that they are declared in your data diagram under the DataSet's 'actions' property) you do not have to write any javascript.

When such an action - let's call it 'actionexample' - is displayed, it already has the necessary code to trigger your platonscript code (which must be binded with the 'dataset.on_actionexample')

Ofcourse you must return some kind of javascript code to show your results to the user